# Is there any way to vectorize this?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there any way for me to vectorize this?

```
for i = 1:totSamples
    sec(i,1)    = str2double(data{4}{i,1}(end-1:end));
    min(i,1)    = str2double(data{4}{i,1}(end-4:end-3));
    hour(i,1)   = str2double(data{4}{i,1}(1:end-6));
end
```

I tried using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370368/1583025 but I get this error:

> Error using end
>   Incorrect cell or structure reference involving "end".
>   Most likely cause is a reference to multiple elements of a cell or structure followed by >additional subscript or structure references.
>
> Error in file (line 64)
>   sec(:,1)    = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s#', data{4}{:,1}(end-1:end)), '%g#'), size(data{4}));

Comment: did you try `cellfun`?

Comment: Did your loop code work in the first place? Unless `sec` is a cell class, how can you store `str2double(data{4}{i,1}(end-1:end))` that will generate 2x1 data?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, the loop code worked. It was just very slow. Why would str2double generate a 2x1 data?

Comment: @alfonzo1955 Because of `(end-1:end)`?

Comment: @Divakar that takes the last two elements of the string

Comment: @alfonzo1955 can my answer provide a further speedup?

Comment: @thewaywewalk no, when I tested it, it was slower than my new solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem using cellfun:

```
secs = cellfun(@(x) x(end-1:end),data{4}(:),'UniformOutput',false);
mins = cellfun(@(x) x(end-4:end-3),data{4}(:),'UniformOutput',false);
hours = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-6),data{4}(:),'UniformOutput',false);

sec(:,1)    = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s#', secs{:}), '%g#'), size(secs));
min(:,1)    = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s#', mins{:}), '%g#'), size(mins));
hour(:,1)   = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s#', hours{:}), '%g#'), size(hours));
```

**EDIT:**

This is a faster way that I found to do it. The cellfuns were taking too long, so I exploited MATLAB's lazy copying:

```
time    = reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s#',data{4}{1:totSamples}),'%d:%d:%d#'), 3,[])';
sec     = time(:,3);
min     = time(:,2);
hour    = time(:,1);

clear time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about `datevec`?
It can actually be done in one line:

I assumed your data and cell structure looks like:

```
% example data
data{4}{1,1} = '05:20:42'
data{4}{2,1} = '06:22:42'
data{4}{3,1} = '07:24:42'
```

then just do:

```
[~,~,~,hour,min,sec] = datevec(data{4},'HH:MM:SS')
```

returns:

```
hour =

     5
     6
     7


min =

    20
    22
    24


sec =

    42
    42
    42
```

Maybe some slightly modifications are necessary, but that's the way. Probably also faster.