# Performance issues by processing huge textfiles

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am facing the problem to extract data out of a textfile which has both numbers and characters in it. The data I want, (the numbers) are separated by rows with characters, describing the following dataset. The textfile is rather large (>2.000.000 lines).

I try to put every dataset (the number of rows between two rows with characters) into a matrix. The matrix should be named according to the description (frequency) in the textline above each dataset. I have a working code, but I face performance problems. Maybe someone can help me to speed it up. One file takes currently about 15 minutes. I need the numbers in matrices to process them further.

Snippet out of Textfile:

```
 21603      2135     21339     21604
 103791        94         1         1         1         4
 21339      1702     21600     21604
 -1
 -1
 2414
    1
 Velocity (magnitude) Response at Structural FE Nodes
     1
 Frequency    = 10.00 Hz
 Result       = Engineering Units
 Component    = Vmag
 Location     = 
 Form & Units = RMS Magnitude in m/s
     1         5         1        11         2         1
     1         0         1         1         1         0         0         0
     1      2161
 0.00000e+000 1.00000e+001 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000
 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000 0.00000e+000
 20008
 1.23285e-004
 20428
 1.21613e-004
```

Here is my code:

```
file='large_file.txt';
fid=fopen(file,'r');
k=1;
filerows=2164986;         % nr of rows in textfile
A=zeros(filerows,6); % preallocate Matrix where textfile should be saved in
for count=1:8   % get rid of first 8 lines
    fgets(fid);
end
name=0;
start=1;
while ~feof(fid)
    a=fgets(fid);
        b=str2double(strread(a,'%s'));  % turn read row in a vector
        if isnan(b(1))==1   % check whether there are characters in the row
            if strfind(a,'Frequency')   % check if 'Frequency' is in the row
                Matrixname = sprintf('Frequency%i=A(%i:%i,:);',name,start,k);
                eval(Matrixname);
                name=b(3);
                for count=1:10   % get rid of next 10 lines
                    fgets(fid);
                end
               start=k+1;
            end
        else  % if there are just numbers in the row, insert it into the matrix
            A(k,1:length(b))=b; % populate matrix A with the row entries
            k = k+1;
        end
    k/filerows % show progress
end
    fclose(fid);
    Matrixname = sprintf('Frequency%i=A(%i:end,:);',name,start);
    eval(Matrixname);
```

Comment: Have you tried running the [matlab profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)? It will help you see which lines of code are taking the most amount of time so that you can figure out what to optimize.

Comment: thanks for your hint!
unbelievable: just by erasing the line 'k/filerows % show progress' I got from ca. 900s -> ca. 350s.
The profiler showed that str2double and strread acount for ca. 2/3 of the time. I used both to split every textline at the spaces and to turn the snippets in a numerical vector. Just now I don't have an idea to do that otherwise faster.

Comment: Great! I will add some additional comments in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading text files line by line is **very** time consuming, especially in Matlab. When I have to read in text files, I usually read in the **entire** file at once. You may be limited by memory, so read it in the largest size chunks your machine can handle. Once it's all in memory, use some kind of logical indexing to find the parts of the data you're interested in. Again, in Matlab, for and while loops are **very** slow. For the data set you have there, I would do the following:

```
fid = fopen(file);
data = fread(fid,[1 maxBytes],'char=>char');
blockIndices = strfind(data,'Velocity'); % Calculate offsets based on data format


% Another approach much faster than for loops
lineData = regexp(data,sprintf('\n'),'split'); % No each line is in a cell
processedData = cellfun(@processData,lineData,'Uniform',false);
function y = processData(x)
   % do something with x
end
```

Once I had the block indices I could calculate offsets to the parts of the data I want. I don't think that two million lines is that much data, and most computers these days have multiple gigabytes of memory, and it doesn't look like each line is more than a couple hundred characters, so the file is probably less than half a GB. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [matlab profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) will help you see which lines of code are taking the most amount of time so that you can figure out what to optimize.

As the original poster determined, the line causing trouble in this case was

```
 k/filerows % show progress
```

Printing to the screen many times is very time consuming. If you want to show progress without slowing the code way down, you could do

```
if mod(k,filerows/100) == 0
    disp('k rows processed');
end
```

That code will cause an update to be displayed 100 times, or every 3.5 seconds in that particular case.

If you want to get really fancy, check out waitbar, but it is usually overkill.

Comment: Thanks, that already helped a lot!
Now I tried to replace the next troublesome line by sth faster:
b=str2double(strread(a,'%s')); acounts for 2/3 of the time now.
In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363132/why-is-str2double-so-slow-in-matlab-as-compared-to-a-mex-function it's suggested to replace str2double() with sscanf(sprintf('%s#', b{:}), '%g#')'. The problem is that this won't work if there is a row containing numbers and letters. Instead of giving me NaN elements in a vector where the letters were I get just an empty vector, discarding the number elements too. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the sscanf-solution to work. I used that function to replace the str2double function to gain some speed as suggested in [Why is str2double so slow in matlab as compared to a mex-function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363132/why-is-str2double-so-slow-in-matlab-as-compared-to-a-mex-function).
Sadly it didn't do too much, but at least it helped a bit.

So, start was ca. 850s

Profiler after removing progress-status: ca. 450s

Profiler after replacing str2double by sscanf: ca.330s

The code now is:

```
file='test.txt';
fid=fopen(file,'r');
k=1;
filerows=2164986;         % nr of rows in textfile
A=zeros(filerows,6); % preallocate Matrix where textfile should be saved in
for count=1:8   % get rid of first 8 lines
    fgets(fid);
end
name=0;
start=1;
while ~feof(fid)
    a=fgets(fid);
       b=strread(a,'%s');
       b=sscanf(sprintf('%s#', b{:}), '%g#')';
       if isempty(b)   % check whether there had been characters in the row
           if strfind(a,'Frequency')   % check whether 'Frequency' was in the row
               Matrixname = sprintf('Frequency%i=A(%i:%i,:);',name,start,k);
               eval(Matrixname);
                b=str2double(strread(a,'%s'));
                name=b(3);
                for count=1:8   % get rid of next 8 lines
                    fgets(fid);
                end
                start=k+1;
            end
        else  % if there were just numbers in the row, insert it into the matrix
            A(k,1:length(b))=b; % populate matrix A with the row entries
            k = k+1;
        end
end
fclose(fid);
Matrixname = sprintf('Frequency%i=A(%i:%i,:);',name,start,k);
eval(Matrixname);
```

[image: Profiler after removing progress-status and before replacing str2double]

[image: Profiler after replacing str2double by sscanf]